# rationally connected by a smooth curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth, rationally connected variety over $\mathbb{C}$. A priori, this means that for any two points $p,q\in X$, there is a rational curve $C$ containing $p$ and $q$. Can $C$ be taken to be smooth?

Comment: Yes. Look in Koll\'ar's book _Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties_ for all kinds of results like this. What you want is somewhere in Chapter IV.

Comment: Nice question !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg:Dear Georges, I believe Theorem IV.3.9 gives an affirmative answer in the case where X is projective and dimX>2.

Comment: @Relapsarian: thanks for the reference! it helped.

Comment: Dear @adrido: you are absolutely right. Thanks for your precise reference.

Comment: Dear @adrido, did you notice that Theorem IV.3.9 does **not** answer your question? It only  says that in a rationally connected smooth variety $X$ of dimension $\geq 3$ you can join two points by a smooth rational curve **provided both points are in some mysterious open subset  $X^0\subset X$ of the variety**.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Dear Georges, you are right, it does not give an answer for general $X$. There are two theorems in the version I have: http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-03276-3. There is theorem IV.3.9.4 which does not assume properness and requires the points to lie on some largest open set. There is also IV.3.9 which assumes properness but requires no further assumption on where the points are.

Comment: Dear adrido: but this is fantatic! Actually most of the varieties studied in algebraic geometry are complete and theorem IV (3;9;3) on page 203 indeed gives a great answer to your very interesting  question for those. I'm learning a lot from you, thanks a lot ! Unfortunately I can't upvote your question more than once :-)

Comment: Dear adrido and @GeorgesElencwajg: sorry for being sloppy in my original comment. I was assuming we were talking about proper varieties, but now I see that was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Dear Georges, you are very welcome! But it's really me who should thank you! After all, I've been learning from your posts ever since I joined MSE.

Answer (score 1):

No: an amusing counterexample is obtained by taking for $X$ a rational curve singular at $p$ !

**EDIT**
This is a counterexample with $X$ singular (I had forgotten that adrido required a smooth variety).
However, in the positive direction,  there also exist singular varieties such that two arbitrary points $p,q$ can  always be joined by a smooth rational curve
A quadratic conic hypersurface   $X\subset \mathbb A^n$ with apex  $O$  is such an example:
Given two points  $p,q\in X$, they are either aligned with $O$ and thus can be joined by a ruling (=line through $O$) of $X$, or else there exists a plane $P$ containing $p$ and $q$ but not $O$ and thus  $P\cap X$ is a smooth conic joining $p$ and $q$.

Comment: maybe i'm dumb but if $X$ is singular at $p$ then $X$ is not smooth ?

Comment: You are not dumb at all: I misread the question, forgetting that  $X$ is required  to be smooth. I'll delete my answer soon  unless I find a correct argument.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I find the positive result very useful! what properties do you require of a singular $X$ so that there exists a smooth curve through any of its two points?

Comment: Dear adrido, unfortunately I don't know:  I just wrote down the first example that came to my mind, because I love this sort of geometry that would have been familiar to Euclid !